# How to redirect user in drupal before a page loads?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, hook

I have a Drupal site which has two pages A(www.mysite.com/A) and (www.mysite.com/B). I want to create a module which will do the following things

-When a user accesses page A detect it.

-Performs some checks in db to find out whether user has access to A

-If user does not have access to page A then redirect him to page B

-Load page B

I am not able to find out which hooks let me alter the path before page loads. Please Help .

Comment: [hook_url_inbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7)?

Comment: Thanks !! I will try it

Answer (score 1):

If you are the author of the route `A`, you can do this in the `'access callback'` of you `hook_menu()` using `drupal_goto()`, else if you are trying to modify the behavior of another module, you can do this in a `hook_menu_alter()`.

Another option (not pretty), is to implement a `hook_init()` like this:

```
function yourmodule_init() {
  if (current_path() == 'A') {
    // Do some DB checks...
    drupal_goto('B');
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one doubt in this . I have disabled clean_url's . So the path is ?q=A.How to handle this in current_path ? Will the absence of clean_urls affect it ?

Comment: `<?php

/**
* Implementation of hook_menu_alter().
*
* @param array $items
* Menu items keyed by path.
*/
function ajax_privacy_menu_alter(&$items) {

$items['user/%']['access callback'] = 'check_access';
$items['user/%']['access arguments'] = array(1);

}

function check_access($user_id)
{
global $user;

if($user->uid!=$user_id)
drupal_goto('node/24');
else
drupal_goto('user/'.$user_id);

}` Tried this and it worked..but it is giving "too many redirects" error..I guess it is because of line...drupal_goto('user/'.$user_id);...Please help

Comment: Yes, `current_path()` handles non-clean urls. Always prefix your functions with the name of your module (i.e. `ajax_privacy_check_access`) and yes, don't do the second `drupal_goto()` as you are already on this page, instead, `return TRUE;`

Comment: I tried doing return TRUE . But the wepage gives me the following error Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.It is giving 500 Internal sever error

Comment: Replace `user/%` with `user/%user`, which is the correct route

Comment: Thanks..Tried it . Still getting internal server error

Comment: You should paste your error log so we can help you then